# Only get specific columns

Tags: entity-framework

Can I make my EF objects retrieve only specific columns in the sql executed?  If I am executing the below code to retrieve objects, is there something I can do to only get certain columns if wanted?

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
{
    return _ctx.CreateQuery<T>(typeof(T).Name).Where<T>(exp);
}
```

This would generate a select clause that contains all columns.  But, if I have a column that contains a large amount of data that really slows down the query, how can I have my objects exclude that column from the sql generated?

If my table has Id(int), Status(int), Data(blob), how can I make my query be

```
select Id, Status from TableName
```

instead of

```
select Id, Status, Data from TableName
```

From the suggestion below, my method is

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp, Expression<Func<T, T>> columns)
{
    return Table.Where<T>(exp).Select<T, T>(columns);
}
```

And I'm calling it like so

```
mgr.GetBy(f => f.Id < 10000, n => new {n.Id, n.Status});
```

However, I'm getting a compile error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'Entities.BatchRequest'

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Sure. Projection does this:

```
var q = from r in Context.TableName
        select new 
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            Status = r.Status
        }
```

Here's an actual example (obviously, my DB has different tables than yours). I added my EF model to LINQPad and typed the following query:

```
from at in AddressTypes
select new
{
    Id = at.Id,
    Code = at.Code
}
```

LINQPad shows me that the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[AddressTypeId] AS [AddressTypeId], 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code]
FROM 
    [dbo].[AddressType] AS [Extent1]
```

None of the other fields from the table are included.

**Responding to updated question**

Your `columns` argument says it takes a type T and returns the same type. Therefore, the expression you pass must conform to this, or you need to change the type of the argument, i.e.:

```
public IEnumerable<U> GetBy<U>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp, Expression<Func<T, U>> columns)
{
    return Table.Where<T>(exp).Select<T, U>(columns);
}
```

Now the expression can return any type you care to use.

Comment: I want to do this in a generic manner so that I can simply add another argument to the GetBy method call that is the columns that should be returned.

Comment: You need to pass a select expression along with your where expression, then, i.e.: var foo = GetBy(r => r.Id == someId, r => new { r.Id, R.Status });

Comment: Edited my post above with more info

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't understand why it's still complaining.  In my example, I am querying for type BatchRequest and want to return BatchRequest with a limited number of columns.  I believe my GetBy is correct, but it's the call that is reporting the error.

Comment: Because r => new { ... } doesn't return an instance of BatchRequest; it returns an instance of an anonymous type. r => new BatchRequest { ... } also won't work **if** BatchRequest is an Entity type, for reasons which won't fit in this comment box. But r => new SomeNonEntityType { ... } will work with the generic method in my answer; you don't have to use an anonymous type.

Comment: OK, I think what this all means is that I can't really accomplish what I'm attempting.  But, shouldn't the GetBy return IEnumerable<U> instead of IENumerable<T>?

Comment: You're right about IEnumerable<U>, yes. Regarding using the entity type, the short answer is that the EF doesn't return partially materialized instances, for various good reasons. So you need to project onto a different type to return only a portion of the data.

Comment: It does work with views. But views are trickier to map correctly, as they have no keys.

Comment: I suspect that the success with views is dependent on your setup. In my case, I have a database first setup against Oracle. Mapping to a view will "guess" the correct keys, but will create a read-only `DefiningQuery` which selects the entire view in the `from` clause. So projection is pointless since the entire view is selected regardless.

Comment: The question was asking how to select specific columns using Entity Framework only. The answer was using LINQ. Althou it works, it should be more accordingly.