# Getting only specific columns in entity framework lambda join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am surprised I cannot find a solution for this on the web, but wording the search terms was a bit difficult. The question I have is about generating entity SQL that only returns the needed columns in a group join using Lambda syntax.

The following is a "toy" example. I am not joining on two entities, rather on an enumerated list and an entity. And tunnelling is not an acceptable answer. I need to apply this to a much larger problem using a group join and select many.

```
var result1 = clientprofiles.Join(Context.Adjusters,
c => c.AdjusterId,
a => a.AdjusterId,
(c, a) => new {a.ClientAccountId}).ToList();
```

Using Julie Lehrman's Entity profiler, I see that the query is being generated to select every record in the rows that meet the join criteria. How do I pare it down so it only selects the ClientAccountId field in this example?

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531934/entity-framework-only-get-specific-columns could you try `Context.Adjusters.Select(a=> new { a.ClientAccountId})` as your first argument to the join?

Comment: SELECT [Extent1].[AdjusterId] AS [AdjusterId]
FROM   [dbo].[Adjuster] AS [Extent1] ... worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Steve, not sure how to up vote you

Comment: Wrote it up as an answer.  Wasn't sure originally.

Comment: Yeah, but great intuition. I kept trying to make a select below the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project a set of columns on any select from the context, so in your case you can constrain the `Context.Adjusters` parameter by using

```
Context.Adjusters.Select(a=> new { a.ClientAccountId })
```

to constrain the query to just the single column