# Join dynamic query result with an EntitySet using Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following models:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
    public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
    //Many more properties...
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
    //Other properties...
}
```

I need to get the orders of a particular customer. In order not to retrieve too many information, I created a class:

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> {get; set;}
}
```

I have mapping configuration for the `Order` and `OrderLine` classes but none for `CustomerOrder` as I was thinking that I can project data into this class.

I can:

1. Use EF to retrieve the data by specifying includes. After the data is retrieved I can project it into the `CustomerOrder` class. However, will this force EF to retrieve all columns for the main and included tables?
2. Use a custom SQL query to retrieve the required details from the `Order` table (maybe directly from a view). The use Linq to join this resultset with `OrderLine` to have the complete projection. However, will I need to have mapping configuration for the view?

To avoid too many columns and join in the SQL select statement, what is the best way to project the data into `CustomerOrder`?

Comment: You you have a navigational property between Order and OrderLine?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes.

Comment: Projection in your EF query will avoid loading all columns if done properly.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531934/entity-framework-only-get-specific-columns

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, can you show that property in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below.You have to do some changes on your models as well.I have done that.Please see that too.

```
 public class Order
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public int CustomerId {get; set;}
        public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection <OrderLine> OrderLines {get; set;}

        //Many more properties...
    }

public class OrderLine
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}

    //Other properties...
}

public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines {get; set;}
}
```

***Final Query :***

```
var orderList = (from order in _context.Orders
                 from orderLine in order.OrderLines)
                 select new CustomerOrder
                   {
                      CustomerId = order.CustomerId,
                      OrderId = orderLine.OrderId,
                      ProductName= orderLine.Product.ProductName,
                      OrderLines = order.OrderLines
                    }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

**A 1 :** No.Only the projected columns will be fetched from the db.

***Best Approach :*** Always use the custom projection (like `CustomerOrder`).That is the best when we consider the Performance of the EF query.You can use that to send data to the View too (it's like a DTO (Data Transfer Object)).