# EntityFramework: Order of deserializing columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to load an object I wrote the the DB using EntityFramework.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [key]
    public long ID {get; set;}


    private string m_someField {
    public string SomeField {
    get
    {
        return m_someField;
    }
    set
    {
            //DO SOMETHING THAT NEEDS THE VALUE OF SomeField2...
    }
    }

    public string SomeField2 { get; set;}
}
```

How can I Tell EF to first fill in SomeField2 and only then the fill other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if EF can load columns in a certain order, and can't think of a use case requiring it.

You could only load the SomeField2 column using [projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531934/only-get-specific-columns/1532034#1532034), and then load the entire object again and merge it into the first one.

However, why not just have a SetSomeField() method that you can either call in the setter of SomeField2, or after the object has been loaded?